# Rails3 irb console vs rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, irb

Using Rails3 and Ruby 1.9.2, I am new, just learning Ruby/Rails--

When I run `irb` I end up with `irb(main):001:0>` which is fine.

However when I run `rails console` I also end up with `irb(main):001:0>` and I thought, based on the book I'm reading and online tutorials that I should be seeing `>>`. Is the Rails Console I'm thinking of a gem that I need to install, something else, or am I just wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: [This link](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/what-are-the-differences-between-irb/) might be helpful for Rubyists:-). It describes the difference between several Ruby Console's.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The exact prompt you'll see in irb can vary and I see the same one you do in Rails 3. It's nothing to worry about.  In fact, I see the simple prompt in plain irb, and the full prompt in rails console :-)

They are both irb, it's just that rails console is set up such that the rails environment is all set and ready to work with, while regular irb has almost nothing loaded by default.

Comment: Haha glad to know I didnt mess something up. Thanks.